# finding area of convergence for Fibonacci Generating Function Formula

Tags: divergent-series

The following text is from the book A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory by J H Goldenman :)

[image]

---

Checking the process again and again I found no restriction for x (i.e. the area of convergence). However, for x=1 we have $\infty = -1$. When we say $1+x+x^2+ \dots = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$, valid for $|x|<1$, that's becasue $1+x+x^2+ \dots + x^n = \dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ for any $x$, then we impose $-1<x<1$ in order to make the series convergent for $n \to \infty$; But how the l.h.s of Fibonacci Generating Function Formula doesn't show divergence when written in a close form?

Comment: Not that I care that much one way or the other, but why the "cute" change of author's name in your post? If you're worried about posting too long an excerpt of copyrighted material, the name change won't help if the publisher wants to make an issue. In any case, it doesn't bother me, and it's a good question that generated some good answers.  -- Joe Silverman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ satisfies

$$\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0,$$

and the reciprocal $x = \phi^{-1}$ satisfies

$$1 - x - x^2 = 0.$$

Furthermore,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}= \phi.$$

The ratio test specifies a radius of convergence for $\sum F_k x^k$ equal to $\phi^{-1}$ since

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{F_{k+1}|x|^{k+1}}{F_k |x|^k} = \phi |x|,$$

with absolute convergence for $|x| < \phi^{-1}.$

Clearly the power series can't converge everywhere since the denominator of the generating function tends to $0$ as $x \to \phi^{-1}$.

You have to be careful applying arithmetic operations to infinite sums as if they were real numbers. Your manipulations of $F(x)$ are not valid for every $x$ unless you know a priori that the series is convergent.

For example, if we write $S = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$ and then argue that

$$xS = x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots \\ \implies S - xS = 1 \\ \implies S = \frac{1}{1-x},$$

we don't find the sum of an infinite series with infinite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The power series of the generating function is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n x^n$. By applying the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), we have convergence when

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left| \frac{F_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{F_n x^n} \right| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\left| x \right|  = \phi |x| <1,
$$

where the last result in the limit is a famous property about the [quotient of successive Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients).

Therefore, the radius of convergence around zero is $1/\phi$, where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the Golden Ratio. In other words, when $|x|<1/\phi$, the power series will converge.

I took the liberty of using Mathematica to plot the first 30 terms of the power series. The (approximate) series is shown in blue; the generating function is shown in red; and the interval of convergence is partitioned off by the vertical green lines.

[image]